# How to block/remove registration of new customers in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer, customer-account, website-restriction

I want to disable the possibility to register as a new customer on the frontend of my Magento 2 Community Edition store (new customers are being created through a different process).

I think I could remove the "Create an Account" link from the top menu and remove the "New Customers" block on the right of the Customer Login page, but I'm looking for a more tight blocking of this functionality. I assume you could still enter the `example.com/customer/account/create/` URL manually and see the registration form.

---

[image]

Comment: Whats wrong with that. You can also override that controller and redirect user or something like that. Or set some error message in session and redirect to the same page along with removing the top link and new customers block.

Comment: Try this also. https://github.com/deved-it/magento2-disable-customer-registration Though not sure how this wroks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Magento 2 has a system in place to facilitate disabling customer registration. The customer module includes a model of which it's the sole purpose to return a boolean `true` or `false` to indicate if customer registration is allowed. The "Create an Account" link block, the "New Customers" block template (on the Customer Login page) **and the Customer Account Create and CreatePost Controllers** consult that model and based on it's return value they do or do not display their content.

This model is `\Magento\Customer\Model\Registration`:

```
namespace Magento\Customer\Model;
class Registration
{
    /**
     * Check whether customers registration is allowed
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

At first, it seems a bit weird to have a whole class that just returns `true`, but this is in place to facilitate a single point where the Magento 2 Enterprise module *WebsiteRestrictions* can hook into to manipulate the returned boolean value based upon the Website Restrictions configuration you can set in the back end of an Enterprise shop.

You can use that very same construction to disable customer registration on your own in your Magento 2 Community Edition, like the module pointed out in the comments (https://github.com/deved-it/magento2-disable-customer-registration) is also doing. Just create an *after* Plugin on the `isAllowed()` method:

**`app/code/MyStore/Customer/Plugin/Customer/Model/RegistrationPlugin.php`:**

```
namespace MyStore\Customer\Plugin\Customer\Model;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
class RegistrationPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param Registration $subject
     * @param boolean $result
     */
    public function afterIsAllowed(Registration $subject, $result)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**`app/code/MyStore/Customer/etc/di.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Registration">
        <plugin name="MyStoreCustomerRegistrationDisable" type="MyStore\Customer\Plugin\Customer\Model\RegistrationPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Of course you can also introduce a config setting to decide whether to return `true` or `false`, just like was done in the linked module on GitHub.

Comment: This solution is not working for magento 2.2.10, for what is worth neither the github module

Comment: This was 3 years ago on Magento 2.1. Please post back here if you find a solution for Magento 2.2 (2.2.10).

Comment: I know, It's just a clarification for new readers.

Comment: I've found a CustomerAuthorization class in vendor/magento/Customer/Model/Plugin that contains a function called "aroundIsAllowed" that looks like it's enforcing the use of EE's api, I'm not sure though, but I'll bet that adobe is taking care of business.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18533

Comment: there.. it was kinda "hacky" but it works, see my answer bellow.

Comment: Not sure why people say, this is not working anymore. It's working perfectly in Magento 2.4

Answer (score 2):

As an additional answer for a quick fix.

In your theme create file `customer_account_create.xml` in `Magento_Customer/layout`

File contents to be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="customer_form_register" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

To remove registration link from the login page

Create file `customer_account_login.xml` in `Magento_Customer/layout`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="customer.new" remove="true"/>

    </body>

</page>
```

Then to remove the registration link from the top links bar

Create file `default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```

As long as you have recaptcha enabled on customer sign ups, it would not be possible to sign up.

Comment: you should mention on which Magento version were you working on.

Comment: Poster just said M2... Anyway, 2.2 - 2.4 should be fine. But tested on 2.3 - 2.4. 
2.2 was just terrible branch of M2 and hopefully everyone has upgraded to 2.3 now.

Comment: The tag is magento 2.1, so you didn't tested on 2.2, but you're claiming that it works and although my solution was tested on 2.2.10 your comment on my answer implies that yours is a solution that works on 2.2.

Comment: I wouldn't get too hung on it. Life goes on and people need up to date answers. Moving on

Comment: Learn your manners boy.

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution didn't worked on magento 2.2.10, the workaround in my case was to edit the file **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml** and comment the block "**Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink**" like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="top.links">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link" name="my-account-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Account</argument>
                <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">110</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
<!--
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink" name="register-link">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create an Account</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
-->
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link"
               template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
...<!--the file continues -->
```

This will remove the "Create an Account" link on the top menu.

Then to remove the "New Customers" block on the login page I've edited the file **vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_login.xml**
and comment the block "**Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info**" like this:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>Customer Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
        <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
            </block>
<!--
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="Magento_Customer::newcustomer.phtml"/> 
-->
        </container>
<!--the file continues -->
```

After that it's needed to run this commands as the magento file system owner on the magento installation directory:

1. bin/magento setup:upgrade
2. bin/magento setup:di:compile
3. bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (with the proper locale)
4. bin/magento cache:clean

Finally to prevent any user from accessing the url **example.com/customer/account/create**

I've created a redirection on the server to the home page, in my case with nginx.

```
location /customer/account/create {
    rewrite ^/customer/account/create https://www.example.com/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this. Does this still work for 2.4?

Comment: @zlep I didn't test it on 2.4

Comment: To remove that block, you just need to do 

<referenceBlock name="customer.new" remove="true"/>

Comment: @elfling if you have a better answer feel free to post it.

Comment: @Typo - No problem, I've added another solution to this answer for a quick fix version

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Enterprise Edition's Company Accounts, there is one more place to block.

app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Company/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>

        <referenceBlock name="register.link.container" remove="true"/>

    </body>
</page>
```