# Magento 2.2: How to completely disable customer login and registration

Tags: magento2, module, customer, customer-account, registration

I have seen plenty of solutions for Magento 1.9, but I have not been able to find any conclusive way of disabling user accounts for Magento 2.

I'm developing a custom theme whose parent is `Magento/blank`.

I have no problem removing the login,signup,wishlist etc. from the frontend using XML and I've managed to remove any mention of customer accounts from the orders page (though I don't remember which process I followed to do so).

However, when my site loads I get an error in the console: `Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen`. Further, if the site is rendered as plain html then the login form is visible.

There will never be any customer accounts allowed on the store, so I'd like to remove all references to accounts on all pages.

I have followed [7ochem's answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/168133/how-to-block-remove-registration-of-new-customers-in-magento-2) to create a custom module for registration removal, modified for Magento 2 as follows:

**`app/code/[Vendor_name]/[Module_name]/registration.php`**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor_name]_[Module_name]',
    __DIR__
);
```

**`app/code/[Vendor_name]/[Module_name]/etc/module.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[Vendor_name]_[Module_name]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**`app/code/[Vendor_name]/[Module_name]/Plugin/RegistrationPlugin.php`**

```
namespace [Vendor_name]\[Module_name]\Plugin;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Registration;
class RegistrationPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param Registration $subject
     */
    public function afterIsAllowed(Registration $subject)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Using the  code inspector (firefox-aurora), I can see a script which contains the variable `window.authenticationPopup = ...`, so I presume that this module is not working properly.

***EDIT:***

Following JoshCarter's comments, I have added the following file:

**`app/code/[Vendor_name]/[Module_name]/etc/di.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Registration">
        <plugin name="[Vendor_name]_[Module_name]::after" type="[Vendor_name]\[Module_name]\Plugin\RegistrationPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

After uploading this to the server, I executed the following commands:

```
$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

During compilation, I receive the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException] Plugin class [Vendor_name][Module_name]\Plugin\RegistrationPlugin doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Joshua, have you created a di.xml as mentioned in  7ochem's answer?

Comment: I was under the impression that module.xml is used in place of it in magento 2.

Comment: di.xml isn't existent in Magento 1.x and was introduced in Magento 2.x

Comment: Ok I just went and looked at the link to the git repo in 7ochem's answer and I can see now why the changes weren't being registered.

Now, when I run the setup:di:compile command in the terminal, I am receiving the error '[InvalidArgumentException] Plugin class [Vendor_name]\[Module_name]\Plugin\RegistrationPlugin doesn't exist'.

Will update the question now.

Comment: Oh I just didn't realise that di.xml files were used inside modules at all (I've never created one before).

Comment: Thats fair enough Joshua - a lot of new concepts are introduced in M2. Looking at the new error you've got, it looks as though there must be an error with the actual plugin class (or the declaration of the class in the di.xml) - I'd run through and check the namespace & class declaration are correct in the Plugin class and that the declaration inside di.xml is correct.

Comment: Well I feel stupid.. forgot to add the `<?php` declaration at the beginning of the class file.

Do you think I should delete this question?

Comment: Ah!! Im sure i speak for a lot of developers when i say sometimes you need to make a mistake like that to never make it again. I've added an answer now so it's up to you if you delete it. Tried to explain the di.xml file abit for you too.

Comment: Ah no problem. Thanks for the info! Just didn't think it would be worth answering my own question with such a minor change.

Well the module seems to be registered and enabled properly, but now I'm actually receiving two (duplicate) warnings from the console about password fields on the homepage, rather than the one I was getting before... so I guess that the 'registration' element of my question is now answered, but I am yet to remove the login. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72446/discussion-between-joshcarter-and-joshua-flood).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just wanted to add a bit of information as an answer here on di.xml, what it is, and some new concepts of Magento 2 introduced by the file. I get this doesn't completely answer the question, but Joshua looks to have missed this file out and if you read our discussion in the comments you can see that he wasn't sure of the file because he hadn't used it before.

di = Dependency Injection - It allows us to declare a whole host of new classes and class types. It might be worth having a read up on the [docs for Dependency Injection by Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html)

It can be included inside `etc/` `etc/frontend/` or `etc/adminhtml`

Pretty self explanatory but, classes declared in `etc/frontend/` would only be executed on the frontend of the site and vise versa for `etc/adminhtml` - similar to the config nodes in Magento 1.x's `etc/config.xml`..

Inside etc/di.xml we can declare:

- Plugins
- Preferences
- Types
- Virtual Types
- Arguments

And probably a few more things i've not mentioned. For further reading have a look at the docs page for the file itself - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html

In your case, you're declaring a Plugin, which you could call an Interceptor, they can then intercept before/after/around any public function. This makes Magento 2.x massively flexible and really allows Magento developers to almost completely disregard Observers and class rewrites in Magento 2.

However, sometimes, theres nothing you can do but have to rewrite a class, like in Magento 1.x. For this you can use a preference in Magento 2 as described in the docs in the link above.

From the comments we've had - it looks as though you've forgot the di.xml and once you created it there's probably just a simple mistake in the Plugin class itself.

Hopefully this helps demystify the new concept of the di.xml file a bit!

***EDIT:***

Adding the line

`<referenceBlock name="customer_form_login" remove="true"/>`

to the body of `default.xml` removes the input fields from /customer/account/login, which is where the user is redirected if they attempt to access /customer/account/create following the addition of the module in OP.

Further to this, adding the line

`<referenceBlock name="authentication-popup" remove="true"/>`

removes the hidden username/password fields from pages, not including the checkout.

Comment: Thanks again! Just gonna leave this up for a little while and work out a solution for removing login so I can add it to your answer, then the green tick is yours!